# Compiling an entire Nodejs full stack app to an android app

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I have a very basic web application written in Nodejs and HTML/CSS/Javascript. This app would not be requiring anything from the internet and should be able to run locally. I want to run this app in 2-3 android devices. Therefore I wanted each app to be a self sufficient application with both front end and backend of its own. However as I think about this night not be possible.

I am also willing to host my Nodejs server on Heroku and have my front end HTML/CSS/Javascript be an app but I am not sure how I would go about doing that.

Comment: You'll be able to reuse most of your code, but it won't run like a web server, like node.js. You'll have to refactor all of your server-side code into a library that can just run client-side

Comment: (or do the heroku thing, if you want to keep it a node.js server)

Comment: as for how to run it on an Android, you'll be wanting to look up how to use a WebView and using project-defined files instead of a website. That's a bit of a rabbit hole